# Access CFBundleIdentifier with Macro

Tags: ios, macros, llvm, target

I need to check the CFBundleIdentifier in a macro to check which target is running to determine whether or not I can import a file but I can't figure it out.

```
#if TARGET_IS_XYZ
#import SomeFile.h
#endif
```

I tried:

```
#define TARGET_IS_XYZ [[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"] isEqualToString:@"com.app.xyz"]
```

but then realized that the [NSBundle maindBundle] isn't available until runtime so I can't use that. Is there any other way to either get the CFBundleIdentifier or check which target is running?

*P.S. By target I mean app target, not iOS or OSX.*

Comment: Your question seems to tangle up run time and build time tasks. In all cases, does "target is running" really mean "target is being built"?

Answer (score 0):

Your macro might be able to accomplish your intent by inspecting either TARGETNAME or PROJECT environment vars. Alternately you might set each build variant to set a unique environment var.
There are also ways (whose syntax escapes me now ): to use environment vars and macros to set values in your info.plist file at build time, which would allow you to manage both appname and your file includes from a single point.